# Oracle regex - encoding issue

Tags: regex, oracle, encoding

In an Oracle 10 database, I did a small test:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('İF', '[Iİ]F', 'DONE', 1, 0, 'i') FROM dual;
```

This does not seem to match the regex. However, when I remove the last parameter (case insensitive regex parameter), the regex matches:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('İF', '[Iİ]F', 'DONE', 1, 0) FROM dual;
```

Below queries also returns **"DONE"**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('IF', '[Iİ]F', 'DONE', 1, 0) FROM dual;
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('iF', '[Iİ]F', 'DONE', 1, 0, 'i') FROM dual;
```

Character set of the database is **UTF8**.

What should I do to make this regex work?

PS: In Turkish language, uppercase version of the character **"i"** is **"İ"**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Equivalence Class](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#i1008619) `[[=i=]]`:

```
SQL> select regexp_replace('İF', '[[=i=]]f', 'DONE', 1, 0, 'i') from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('İF','[[=I=]]F'
------------------------------
DONE

SQL> select regexp_replace('if', '[[=i=]]f', 'DONE', 1, 0, 'i') from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE('IF','[[=I=]]F'
------------------------------
DONE
```

**Edit**: There seems to be a bug in some versions of Oracle with the REGEXP search functions regarding `ı->I` and `i->İ`

One possible workaround is to use the `NLS_UPPER` or `NLS_LOWER` functions that work reliably with the correct `NLS_SORT` setting:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_sort=XTURKISH;

Session altered

SQL> select regexp_replace(NLS_UPPER('İF'), 'İF', 'DONE', 1, 0) from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE(NLS_UPPER('İF'
------------------------------
DONE

SQL> select regexp_replace(NLS_UPPER('if'), 'İF', 'DONE', 1, 0) from dual;

REGEXP_REPLACE(NLS_UPPER('IF')
------------------------------
DONE
```